# SQL Procedure - use aggregate in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have:

1. Distributors in Disributor table. (DisributorID = PK)
2. Regions in Region Table. (DisributorID = FK)

I want to store a procedure that accepts a number from user as a @scale which is number of Regions each distributor has. procedure should go and check which Distributors has reached that @scale number and add 10 dollars to their salary!

---

I have this code, but it feels weird/Stupid/not working! I think the way i look at the problem is wrong.

```
    create procedure RewardDistributors (@scale int = null)
    as
    if @scale is null
    begin
    raiserror ('Please provide A value!', 16, 1)
    end
else
    begin
    if not exists
    (select COUNT(RegionID) from Region having COUNT(RegionID) >= @scale)
    begin
    raiserror ('No one reached this number yet', 16, 1)     
    end

    else
    begin 
        update Distributor 
        set wage = (wage + 10)
        where DistributorID = 
        (select DistributorID, COUNT(*) from Region group by DistributorID having COUNT(*) >= @scale)
    end
end
```

return

Comment: Why would you throw an error if there wasn't a record found...?  Why not just... return zero records...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simplification of your proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE RewardDistributors
    @Scale INT
AS

UPDATE Distributor
SET wage = wage + 10
WHERE DistributorID IN (
    SELECT DistributorID
    FROM Region
    GROUP BY DistributorID
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= @Scale
)

PRINT CAST(@@ROWCOUNT AS VARCHAR) + ' rows updated.'
```

Don't allow the parameter to be NULL if you're just going to check if its NULL. You also don't need to perform any tests - just do the update and then print how many rows were updated. You can modify that if you really want distinct output messages.

Comment: @IvyKnm - you bet. The reason your original query didn't work is because you included a `COUNT(*)` in your subquery, as @SqlZim pointed out below. Your syntax for creating the proc was also a little strange - it looks like you're trying to mix creating a function and creating a proc (a proc doesn't have parentheses around the params, and shouldn't include the `return` keyword)